# web service in eclipse with tomcat, NoClassDefFoundError: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat

I am following a tutorial for a simple sample web service at http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/comment-page-1/#comment-130057 - He carefully lists the libraries needed, and they are in both the tomcat lib folder and in the "user libraries" section of the web service itself.  (Putting those there got me past my last fatal error message trying to get this done.)  I've seen a post on this error with this class indicating that an "old servlet.jar is probably sitting somewhere."; I cannot find one in either eclipse or the tomcat library directory.  There is a servlet-api.jar in the tomcat lib directory, and it actually has the ServletContainerInitializer in it.

This is Tomcat 7, eclipse Juno, and no I don't want to stop and learn Maven first.  I saw one other post that said that after the poster had cleaned out and reinstalled the JRE/JDK, Tomcat, and eclipse, the problem went away.  I suppose if I buy a new machine it will go away, too, but I'm hoping for something less drastic.

I don't expect anyone to know what the problem is -- can someone tell me how to chase it down?  I'm posting the first part of the console log, in case that's any help...

```
Mar 3, 2013 8:53:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;PATH=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\local\derby\bin;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\12.0\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Roxio\OEM\AudioCore\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;.
Mar 3, 2013 8:53:41 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:FirstWS' did not find a matching property.
Mar 3, 2013 8:53:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 3, 2013 8:53:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 3, 2013 8:53:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 794 ms
Mar 3, 2013 8:53:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 3, 2013 8:53:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.37
Mar 3, 2013 8:53:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1628)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializer(ContextConfig.java:1659)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1569)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: New info -- I did rename the directory in which Tomcat was installed and re-installed (unzipped) it.  No change in above behavior.

Comment: Ok, more new info - In eclipse, in "Web App Libraries" for the web service that I am attempting to run, there seem to be 9 jar files that I put there when attempting a different tutorial that I've now abandoned.  I can't figure out how to get rid of them.  The 'delete' option is greyed out when I right-click on the jar filename.  They are likely candidates, since others don't seem to have this problem.  How do I get rid of them out of this project?

Comment: You need servlet 3.0 jar

Comment: I've read elsewhere that servlet.jar from 3.0 is not supported by Tomcat 6, I would suppose this would also be true of 7, though I am not sure.  I just created a new web service project and copied just the java and web.xml files into it; same error.

Comment: No it works with Tomcat 7.

Comment: You are missing the `servlet-api.jar` library from your classpath. This library comes with Tomcat 7, and you may have missed adding the Tomcat libraries to your project build path.

Comment: It is odd -- servlet-api.jar is indeed there in the Tomcat 7 distribution, but this is not a build-time error, it is a run-time error.  Can not having that in my build path cause a run-time error somehow?